# How to redirect a referral link back to index using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have multiple secondary domains which redirect to my primary domain.

Example. This would be written into the htaccess of www.secondarydomain1.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://primarydomain.com/?utm_source=redirect&utm_medium=secondarydomain1.com&utm_campaign=301redirect$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I write the htaccess of www.primarydomain.com, so that I can match a condition of:

IF URL is http://primarydomain.com/?utm_source=redirect&utm_medium=secondarydomain1.com&utm_campaign=301redirect OR http://primarydomain.com/?utm_source=redirect&utm_medium=secondarydomain2.com&utm_campaign=301redirect , etc,
to redirect back to primarydomain.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=redirect&utm_medium=((secondarydomain1|secondarydomain2)\.com|secondarydomain3\.me)&utm_campaign=301redirect$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Can I ask why it should be a temporary redirect (302) rather than a 301?

Comment: Also how would it be written if the TLD on the secondary domains were different? E.g. secondarydomain1.com, secondarydomain2.com and secondarydomain3.me

Comment: No 302 is not mandatory. You should use `R=302` while testing and change it to `R=301` afterwards since browsers aggressively cache `301` URLs causing problem in your testing. Check edit for `secondarydomain3.me`

Comment: Ah right that makes sense. What's the difference between using: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]` and `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]` ? As further on in the htaccess, I remove the www from url to make it non-www canonical.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$` means execute rule if HOST is `www.exaple.com` OR `exaple.com`. But `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$` means execute rule if HOST is NOT `example.com`